# How to assign 2 variables with the same parameters in 1 line

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

Just as a learning exercise I wanted to know if there is a way in python 3.x to basically do:

```
a = random.sample(range(30), random.randrange(1,20))
b = random.sample(range(30), random.randrange(1,20))
```

as:

```
a, b = random.sample(range(30), random.randrange(1,20))
```

this doesnt work, of that I know. I also dont know if it is possible to do this without writing.

```
a, b = random.sample(range(30), random.randrange(1,20)), random.sample(range(30), random.randrange(1,20))
```

Thank you for responses in advance.

Comment: `a,b = (lambda s: (s(30,20),s(30,20)))(lambda a,b: random.sample(range(a), random.randrange(b)))` **;-)**

Comment: thank you! that worked beautifully!

Comment: If you're okay with `a` and `b` being the same size, you can do a one-liner with `numpy`: `a, b = np.random.choice(range(30), (2, random.choice(range(20))))`

Comment: @BrettPlemons It was mostly an obfuscation joke, but I'm glad you liked it.

Comment: Thank you @pault for providing a module answer. I am always excited to learn more ways to use numpy, for my particular problem i need 2 different sized lists. But in most cases that is a great idea!

Comment: @molbdnilo Took 4 years but I happened to stumble over your comment and it's hilarious. So, someone got the joke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best option may be a list comprehension:

```
a, b = [random.sample(range(30), random.randrange(20)) for _ in range(2)]
```

Also, you can use a generator expression:

```
a, b = (random.sample(range(30), random.randrange(20)) for _ in range(2))
```

But, since this is *unpacking*, I am not sure if that would be faster.

Comment: For clarity, it would probably be better.Or add it under a big "What you shouldn't do "

Comment: @Aran-Fey, I know, I just wanted to show to OP other ways that sadly doesn't work. But since it seem to bring confusion I have just delete them.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Ok, I'll delete them to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: either of these worked the best for me while still being readable the onlything i changed, which I should have changed in my original code, as for the `random.randrange(20)` to be `random.randrange(1,20)` that way it never generates an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

One method is

```
a,b=[random.sample(range(30), random.randrange(20)) for _ in [0,1]]
```

(`[0,1]` can be replaced with any length-two iterable)

If you're calling  `random.sample(range(30), random.randrange(20))` a lot, you should give it a name:

```
 def random_length_sample():
       return random.sample(range(30), random.randrange(20))
 a = random_length_sample()
 b = random_length_sample()
```